# Need to preserve initial paragraph and character styles in text selection after adding hyperlinks

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am adding hyperlinks to selected text in Word. The selected text may have formatted text in it, such as italics, small caps, bold, etc.
I am able to preserve the CHARACTER styles, i.e., small caps, if the ENTIRE selection is the same character style (e.g., small caps). However, if the text includes unformatted text along with the formatted text, then the character style is replaced with the hyperlink style.
I inserted screenshots of *before* and *after* adding the hyperlinks.

BEFORE (no hyperlinks added):
[image]

AFTER (each line has a hyperlink added):
[image]

What I'm trying to end up with is something like the "SMALL CAPS TEST" as it:

- preserves the initial small caps style
- does not get overwritten with the HYPERLINK style (blue underlined text)

Any help is much appreciated. I'm at a loss on how to step through the style applied to each word or even character in the text selection.

UPDATE:
I managed to get rid of the Hyperlink character style SHOWING up as blue and underlined. However, the character style will still overwrite the previous character styles (i.e., Bold, Small Caps, Italics). Here is my code that will provide the correct character style applied until the Hyperlink is attached. However, if the entire selection is all ONE character style, then it is still preserved (probably due to the code line:
`Selection.style = MyStyle`
I need to be able to apply the correct character style to each character.
Here is my code:
``Sub AddHLINK()

```
    Dim myText, myISBN, myCurrISBN, myURL, myCharStyle, ochr As String
    Dim NoCharSty As Boolean
    Dim MyStyle, MyFont, mychar, mycharstyleb As String
    Dim charcount, j, k As Integer
    
         myURL = "http://www.google.com"


    myText = Selection.Text
    charcount = Len(myText)

    For k = 1 To charcount
        mychar = Selection.Characters(k).Text
        MyStyle = Selection.Characters(k).Style
        
       
        If ActiveDocument.Characters(k).Style = wdStyleTypeCharacter Then
            myCharStyle = MyStyle
         
            NoCharSty = False
         Else
             NoCharSty = True

         End If
    Next k

    MsgBox "the current url is " & myURL
    Stop
    
    ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection.Range, Address:=myURL, TextToDisplay:=myText

    End Sub
```

Comment: Always helps to include your code.

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/49169/how-to-remove-color-formatting-of-links-in-microsoft-word

Comment: How to ask a question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  This may be off-topic for Stack Overflow which is a programming forum: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: You need to edit the xml style definition for the Hyperlink styles. You'll find it in the styles.xml file inside the docx. Delete the entire line that sets the color. The underline can be removed by modifying the style in the usual way. Contrary to what is stated in the question referenced in an earlier comment this does work.

Comment: That seems to work (I actually already did that by changing the font, removing the underline, etc. of the "Hyperlink" style). Thank you for helping!